# Couldn't append svg in html document using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to append an svg image in a html document using d3.js but I don't know why it is not working.

Here's what I wrote in my hello.js:

```
const w = 600;
const h = 600;
let dataset = [];
let x;
let y;
//Creating SVG Element
let svg =  d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 
w).attr("height", h);
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello, D3</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/d3/d3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/hello.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

When I view the source code of my page, I can see that the svg was not created.

I'm using simpleHTTPServer to create a local server and then load my page so I don't think that the browser blocked the script.

EDIT: here's what I see when I inspect the page
[inspect page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ls2ch.png)

Comment: What do you see when you inspect the page? The source code is not altered by d3, d3 forms part of the page.

Comment: @AndrewReid I just edited my post. I added a screenshot of what I see when I inspect page

Comment: @Gyun When your code in `js/hello.js` is executed your `<body>` element is not yet available. Hence, there is nothing to append your `<svg>` element to. Have a look at [*"Where should I put <script> tags in HTML markup?"*](/q/436411) for a thorough explanation as well as multiple solutions.